# How to use qt to obtain playback duration of multiple audio files

Tags: qt

In one scenario, I wanted to get the duration of multiple files at once, but I found that QMediaPlayer's duration was asynchronous and couldn't get the duration correctly;

How to solve this problem?

I tried using connect and durationChanged, but it didn't work as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.